# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)'

Please let from where these two dependencies come from ?